# Как реализовать приватный доступ админа в admin LTD?

Tags: php, yii2, phpmyadmin

что нужно сделать, чтобы другие пользователи, зарегистрировавшиеся на fronted не могли, кроме админа заходить в backend? Но могли, при этом создавать, к примеру, посты в блоге и что-то ещё на сайте?

Comment: Вы бы не могли пояснить, что в Вашем понимании есть frontend и backend?.. а то я в замешательстве...

Comment: смотрите в сторону RBAC

Comment: папка 'site' поделена на: 'backend' -это админ вход в yii2, (admin.site.com) fronted- 'лицо сайта' (site.com) и 'common'  также в 'vendor' подключены модули 'tags-module', 'blog-module' и др. про RBAC - не понятно.. что и где надо искать?

Comment: http://rgblog.ru/page/yii2-i-rbac-kontrol-dostupa-na-osnove-rolej

Comment: сам полноценный ответ написать не могу, поскольку на втором YII не работал, поэтому благославляю всех читающих на написание исчерпывающего ответа.

Answer (score 0):

В самом простом варианте -- сделайте для модели User в backend-приложении  список пользователей прямо в модели, как это сделано в basic приложении:
https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2-app-basic/blob/master/models/User.php

то есть для backend-приложения ограничение будет только этими пользователями, которые записаны в статическую переменную `$users`

Comment: там Yii2 basic ведь, а у меня advanced и у меня в backend нет в models файлов, кроме .gitkeep

Comment: ну и что, у backend-приложения тоже есть модель, она рабоатет с моделью User, которая может иметь  только  1 аккаунт (к примеру admin), который будет задан как там

Comment: т.е нужно создать такой файл User в backand/models?